# chart.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am trying to use the basic example of NG2-Charts (http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/)

In its github repo (https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts) it is mentioned that:

> Important: Embedding Chart.js in application is mandatory!

```
<script src="node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>
```

But when I am embedding this script It is showing an error

> chart.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Does anyone has an idea on how to fix that? Thank you

Comment: It would be because of the reason that require cant be resolved on browser.
you can read about http://browserify.org/ to resolve this.

Comment: @Feeda I have used browserify, still my problem has not been solved

Comment: Could you please explain where you are embedding the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use chart.js in Ionic 2 RC0 just install the library and typings:

```
$ npm install chart.js --save
$ typings install chart.js --save
```

Include the library in the component's header with

```
import 'chart.js/src/chart';
declare var Chart;
```

and use it e.g. for a line diagram with

```
let ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: { your data },
  options:{ your options }
});
```

where `canvas` is the HTML element of the chart in the component's template:

```
<canvas class="line-chart" #canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK! Instead of NPM module use.

```
bower install chart.js --save
```

This will download it to bower_components directives. then include it from there in your scripts

Comment: Even after including the lib in index.html file. I am getting an error
**error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: ng2-charts configuration issue: Embedding Chart.js lib is mandatory**

Comment: You are using https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js right?
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/